# Advanced Excel Change Filtering Behavior

Tags: excel, filtering

Is it possible to change the filtering behavior of Excel in the following fashion:

Lets say I had the following data:

Col A    Col B

Apple    Red

Orange   Orange

Carrot   Orange

Celery   Green

Squash   Yellow

Suppose I filtered column A on values:  Apple, Orange, Carrot.
I want to now filter column B on values:  Orange, Red, and Green.
The only problem is that Green won't appear after I have filtered column A.
I want to join every column on "OR" condition, not on "And" Condition (which is the default behavior of Excel).

So, I want, every row for which column A has Apple, Orange, and Carrot.
And I also want every row for which column B has Green.

Is there a way to change the default behavior so that the columns are "Or'd" and not "Anded"  (excuse my English, but you know what I mean....)

Comment: In Excel 2010 or above you can use [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-a-table-Power-Query-b5610630-f5bf-4ba4-9217-a628f9b89353#__to_filter_multiple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an advanced filter. If your columns are headed 'Fruit' and 'Colour', set up the following criteria in another area of your sheet:-

```
Fruit Colour
Apple
Orange
Carrot
       Green
```

Follow the examples [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b).

Comment: I will accept the answer since based on my question wording, this is a valid answer.  I was hoping there would be a way to change the default from and-ing to or-ing... if you know what I mean (column filters should always display every option, not filter based on currently selected rows).

Comment: Thanks! I know this isn't very interactive - it would be nice if you could have active filters that did logical OR, but don't know how to achieve it.